# Unable to install sodium to Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I've tried running `npm install sodium` in the Heroku console but it just returns

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/sodium
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js --preinstall
npm ERR! Static libsodium was not found at /app/node_modules/sodium/deps/build/lib/libsodium so compiling libsodium from source.
npm ERR! libtool is required, but wasn't found on this system
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:62: libsodium] Error 1
npm ERR! /app/node_modules/sodium/install.js:293
npm ERR!             throw new Error(cmdLine + ' exited with code ' + code);
npm ERR!             ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: make libsodium exited with code 2
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sodium/install.js:293:19)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-08-10T23_25_41_425Z-debug.log
```

I was led to believe Heroku has libtool installed so I don't see why I can't install sodium.